# jQuery: Finding and counting elements that contain a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long set of rows (tr) within a table.

I want to find each occurrence of 'M' within the third td, so I came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function countInstance(needle) {
        var count = 0;
        $("table").find("TR TD:nth-child(3):contains(' "+needle+" ')").each(function() {
            count += 1;
        });
        console.log(count);
    };

    countInstance("M");

});
```

But the console doesn't return a modified count. Ideally I want to search and count occurrences of other variables within other td elements as well, logging each of them to a variable or pushing them to an array.

EDIT:

Mostly solved, but this appears to be slightly inaccurate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function countInstance(tdNum, needle) {
        var count = 0;
        $('table TR').find('TD:nth-child(' +tdNum+ '):contains(' +needle+ ')').each(function() {
            count += 1;
        });
        console.log(count);
    };

    countInstance(3, 'M');

});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `return a modified count`?

Comment: You always look in the same TR TD `$("table").find("TR TD:nth-child(3):contains`

Comment: Arun, that was a convoluted way of saying that the the occurrences aren't being counted.

Comment: To clarify you are trying to count how many `"M"`s (as in the string) are in the 3rd `<td>` tag?

Comment: for accessing a variable/parameter in this call, you can do: `$('table tr').find('td:nth-child(3):contains(' + needle + ')').each(function(){ })`...

Comment: John, that's correct.

Comment: Rohit416, that did it. My syntax was wrong - specifically just placement of apostrophes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function countInstance(tdNum, needle) {
 var contents = $("table tr").find("td:nth-child(" + tdNum + ")").text();
 count = contents.split(needle).length - 1;
 console.log(count);
};

var result1 = countInstance(3, "M");

function countInstance2(tdNum, needle) {
 var count = 0;
    $('table TR').find('TD:nth-child(' +tdNum+ '):contains(' +needle+ ')').each(function() {
  count += 1;
 });
    console.log(count);
};

var result2 = countInstance2(3,"M");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>MMMMMMMMM</td>
        <td>MMMMMMMM</td>
        <td>MMMMMMM</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function countInstance(tdNum, needle) {
        var contents = $("table tr").find("td:nth-child(" + tdNum + ")").text();
        count = contents.split(needle).length - 1;
        console.log(count);
    };

    countInstance(3, "M");

});
```

Comment: This code results in 710 occurrences, compared to mine that results in 708. What could the reason behind that discrepancy be if they're doing nearly the exact same thing?

Comment: I think the discrepancy is still coming from me fully trying to understand what you are asking.  My code above finds the number of `"M"` characters within each `<td>` tag that are the `tdNum` child.  Yours is counting how many `<td>` tags there are that contain any "M" characters and are the `tdNum` child.  https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Sorry, I understand the difference now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.